# Automatically running the same test plan multiple times with different variables

Tags: jmeter

I've created a test plan to do some load testing against HTTP endpoints.  I want to run the same test plan against multiple endpoints, and find myself having to do the following each time:

1. Change variable that determines which endpoint I'm hitting.
2. Run the test.
3. When complete, record results.
4. Clear all results.
5. Back to step 1.

I want to automate this.  Is the following possible?

1. Define a list of endpoints as a variable.
2. For each endpoint in endpoints

   - Run test against endpoint
   - When complete, save results
   - Clear all results.

The things in particular that I don't know how to automate are:

- Starting a test
- Defining an list-style variable
- Clearing all results

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see answers below:

**Starting a test**

Apart from running JMeter from GUI there are several execution options such as:

- [Command line non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) - you can wrap JMeter execution line in operating system batch file
- [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) - integration with Apache Ant build system, more powerful if you're comfortable with it
- [JMeter Maven Plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin) - the same as Ant but for Apache Maven
- Option to run JMeter with CI systems like [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JMeter+Plugin)

**Defining an list-style variable**

JMeter offers "properties" which can be set via *.properties* files (see *user.properties* in /bin folder of your JMeter installation for example) or passed as name/value pairs to JMeter startup script. For instance instead of hard-coding your host in .jmx file you can use [read a property function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P).

1. Set "Server Name or IP" field value to `${__P(myhost,)}`
2. Add `myhost=example.com` line to *user.properties* file in /bin folder of your JMeter installation, restart JMeter and run the test. Request will go to example.com.
3. Alternatively you can pass `myhost` property to JMeter in command-line mode as follows

   ```
   jmeter -Jmyhost=example.com
   ```

Multiple properties can be passed this way:

```
    jmeter -Jproperty1=value1 -Jproperty2=value2 ....
```

And even files via `-p` or `--propfile` JMeter command line argument

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more options and information.

**Clearing all results**

It depends on unattended execution option you'll choose, all of them provide at least one way to delete file and/or folder. Personally I wouldn't delete any results and would rather keep them for future reference. To distinguish different endpoints test runs and to avoid overwriting I would use timestamps like:

```
jmeter -Jhttp.endpoint=my.test.host -n -t your-script.jmx -l my-test-host-results-${date}.jtl
```

where

- `-J` - sets endpoint to my.test.host
- `-n` - tells JMeter to run in non-GUI mode
- `-t` - specifies .jmx file to use
- `-l` - specifies name and location of results file